# Android Add elements to an ArrayList Inside onActivityResult method

Tags: android, kotlin

I am new in android and i have been facing some weird troubles. I need to add elements to an `ArrayList` from inside `onActivityResult` method, with `var` it works perfectly but with arrays or lists it crashes.

I am not trying to pass values from `startActivityForResult` to `onActivityResult`. I'm trying to use `onActivityResult` values out of this method.

Even with a singleton class it crashes.

I need to store the uris to upload every image and get the ids to send it to the server

```
class SellActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private val imgResult = 1
    val imageInfoArray: ArrayList<String?>? = null
    var mId: String? = null

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

        if (requestCode == imgResult && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
            data.data?.also { uri ->
            mId = uri.toString()
            imageInfoArray.add(Info(mId))
        }
    }
}
```

When a try to add elments to the `ArrayList` it throws a null pointer exception. And it seems that even in forward methods I cannot use any array or list. I mean, if i extract the values with vars it works, but in the next method i can't use arrays or lists.
I have not found useful examples to know how to handle this.

Comment: can you try like `val arrayList1 = ArrayList<String>()` instead of `val imageInfoArray: ArrayList<String?>? = null`

Comment: It works! I don't understand the logic behind it, but it works

Comment: arraylist should be initialized(normally using new keyword) before accessing it.. You given null value to it while declaring the variable. So it thrown nullpointerexception